# Generic way for traversing a C++ std::tuple

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

My goal is to have a generic way to traverse a `std::tuple`, and the following code tries to show it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename t, size_t t_idx, typename t_tuple>
concept visit_tuple_element_value = requires(t &&p_t, const t_tuple &p_tuple) {
  {
    p_t.template operator()<t_idx>(
        std::declval<std::add_const_t<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<t_tuple>>>())
    } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};

template <typename t_tuple, typename t_function, size_t t_idx = 0>
requires(visit_tuple_element_value<t_function, t_idx, t_tuple>)

    void traverse_tuple_values(t_function p_function, const t_tuple &p_tuple) {
  if constexpr (t_idx < std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>) {
    if (p_function.template operator()<t_idx>(p_tuple)) {
      traverse_tuple_values<t_tuple, t_function, t_idx + 1>(p_function,
                                                            p_tuple);
    }
  }
}

struct a {};
struct b {};
struct c {};

using my_tuple = std::tuple<b, a, c>;

int main() {

  my_tuple _tuple;

  auto _visitor = [&]<size_t t_idx>(const my_tuple & /*p_tuple*/) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<t_idx, my_tuple>, a>) {
      std::cout << "'a' is at index " << t_idx << std::endl;

    } else {
      std::cout << "'a' is NOT at index " << t_idx << std::endl;
    }
    return true;
  };

  traverse_tuple_values(_visitor, _tuple);
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
'traverse_tuple_values<std::tuple<b, a, c>, (lambda at main.cpp:63:19), 3UL>'
```

I do not understand why `p_function.template operator()<t_idx>(p_tuple)`, and therefore `_visitor`, is being called with `t_idx` equals to 3, if I have in `traverse_tuple_values` the line `if constexpr (t_idx < std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>)`.

`g++ --version` reports `g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0`

Comment: That's only a part of the error message.

Comment: stackoverflow said I had too much code in the question, so I had to remove some. Here it is: main.cpp:47:7: While checking constraint satisfaction for template 'traverse_tuple_values<std::tuple<b, a, c>, (lambda at /home/rodrigo/development/studies/traverse_tuple/main.cpp:63:19), 3UL>' required here
main.cpp:64:39: While checking constraint satisfaction for template 'traverse_tuple_values<std::tuple<b, a, c>, (lambda at /home/rodrigo/development/studies/traverse_tuple/main.cpp:63:19), 3UL>' required here

Comment: `traverse_tuple_values<t_tuple, t_function, t_idx + 1>(p_function, p_tuple);` the `+ 1` will go out of bounds.

Comment: That I could read. The question is why, since I expected 'if constexpr (t_idx < std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>)' to prevent it.

Comment: `std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>` is 3; the largest valid `t_idx` is 2, but when it is 2, `t_idx + 1` is 3.

Comment: I know what is happening. I would like to know why, since I expected 'if constexpr (t_idx < std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>)' to prevent it.

Comment: Your bad `+ 1` is happening **after** you've check for `t_idx < tupleSize_v`.

Comment: Thanks, @Eljay. The corrected code is posted below

Comment: I do not get what is required functionality for this tuple traversal. Why `_visitor` looks this way? Do you realy need index as template parameter? Here is my attempt: https://godbolt.org/z/MT8WKq6ca to iterate over a tuple with indexes.

Comment: I am not smart enough to understand code that uses '...' expansion nor functions that use, like 'std::apply' and yours elegant 'for_each_tuple'.

Answer (score 5):

You check `if constexpr (t_idx < std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>)`. But when index 2 is reached, the compiler tries to instantiate `traverse_tuple_values<..., 3>` because `t_idx + 1` == 2. Then the compiler checks the constraints for the function but `visit_tuple_element_value` with `t_idx = 3` fails.

To solve your problem, you could check for a termination criterion, e.g. `if constexpr (t_idx >= std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>)` and not call itself in this case. Then you don't need the function you want to apply to all elements to return a bool and the concept is not needed anymore either.

Or you can be more explicit with fold expressions:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void traverse_tuple_values_with_index(Func function, const std::tuple<Args...>& tup) {
    [&]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        (function.template operator()<Is>(tup), ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
}
```

this code directly calls `function` once with all indices as template argument.

Alternatively you can remove the need for the index and operate on the element instead on the tuple + index;

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void traverse_tuple_values(Func function, const std::tuple<Args...>& tup) {
    [&]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        (function(std::get<Is>(tup)), ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
}
```

[See demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hbEq3o7jT)

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to avoid fold expressions, as I find them very hard to read and understand.

Comment: I thought so too until I started trying to write them, one gets used to them rather quick

Comment: @canellas This is a perfect time to start learning them.  Eventually you'll hit a point when using recursion that you exceed what the compiler can do or your compile times become enormous.  Using a fold expressions saves you from those issues.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is, thanks to @Eljay:

```
template <typename t_tuple, typename t_function, size_t t_idx = 0>
requires(visit_tuple_element_value<t_function, t_idx, t_tuple>)

    void traverse_tuple_values(t_function p_function, const t_tuple &p_tuple) {
  if constexpr (t_idx < std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>) {
    if (p_function.template operator()<t_idx>(p_tuple)) {
      if constexpr ((t_idx + 1) < std::tuple_size_v<t_tuple>) {
        traverse_tuple_values<t_tuple, t_function, t_idx + 1>(p_function,
                                                              p_tuple);
      }
    }
  }
}
```